# How many different ways can a number be written as a sum of 1, 3, and 5?

Tags: combinatorics

I had a programming question where we had to write code to output, given some number x, all the different ways x can be written as a sum of 1, 3 and 5. So for instance if x=6, then the answer is 4, as x=5+1=3+3=3+1+1+1=1+1+1+1+1+1.

This made me wonder how the same question could be done without using a computer, but I was unsure how one would go about doing this. Please try and explain how this could be done, preferably in the simplest way possible.

Comment: You could compute the coefficient of the $t^x$ term in the series expansion of the function $$\frac1{(1-t)(1-t^3)(1-t^5)}.$$

Comment: Please explain how that method relates to the question as I'm afraid I have very little experience with this sort of counting

Comment: @Guest Well, counting them is different from listing them. If you want to list them, you'd really need to write some sort of program. Counting them is another matter, and Did's suggesting is called a "generating function."

Comment: The result will be a function of the form $f(n)+g(n)$ where $f(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ and $g(n)$ is a period function of period $15$.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a read up about generating functions and give Did's suggestion a shot, thanks!

Comment: For computational purposes a more direct approach is the number of solutions for the diophantine inequation $3n+5m\le x$, where $n,m\in \Bbb N_0$ and $x$ is the desired number to add up.

Answer (score 2):

The generating function approach is to note that if you write:

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-x^3}\frac{1}{1-x^5}\\
&=(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\cdots)(1+x^5+x^{10}+\cdots)\\
&=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots
\end{align}$$

Then $a_n$ counts the number of ways to partition $n$ into values in $1,3,5.$

Then we use the method of partial fractions to write:

$$f(x)=\frac{a}{(1-x)^3}+ \frac{b}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{c}{1-x}+ \frac{dx+e}{1+x+x^2}+\frac{fx^3+gx^2+hx+j}{1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4}$$

You can solve for $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j$.

This is tedious, but you really only need to compute $a,b,c$, and there are tricks for doing so. Then you'll get a formula $c\binom{n+2}{2}+b\binom{n+1}{2}+a\binom{n}{2}$. As noted in comments, $a_n-\left(c\binom{n+2}{2}+b\binom{n+1}{2}+a\binom{n}{2}\right)$ will be periodic of period $15$, so you only have to figure out $a_0,\dots,a_{14}$  to figure out what the "correction" is.

I used Wolfram Alpha to find a,b,c.

It turns out the closed formula is the nearest integer to $\frac{(n+4)(n+5)}{30}=\frac{1}{15}\binom{n+5}{2}$.

I've checked this answer against Marcus's (now-deleted) answer, and it works up to $n=10000$, so I'm pretty sure my arithmetic was accurate.

Answer (score 1):

A bit uncertain if it is worth carrying out the calculations, but anyway: As suggested by Did (and Thomas) the generating function seems a reasonable approach. In order to get a palpable result you may want to use a factorization by noting that $(1-t)(1-t^3)(1-t^5)$ is a divisor of $(1-t^{15})(1-t)(1-t)$ (follows from looking at roots). Carrying out the polynomial division you arrive at a fairly nice looking formula:
$$ f(t)=\frac{1}{(1-t)(1-t^3)(1-t^5)}= \frac{1-t+t^3-t^4+t^5-t^7+t^8}{(1-t^{15})(1-t)^2}$$
Writing $q(t)=1-t+t^3-t^4+t^5-t^7+t^8=q_0+q_1 t+\cdots+q_8 t^8$ 
and expanding the denominator in power-series:
$$ f(t) = q(t)(1+t^{15}+t^{30}+...) (1+2t+3t^2+4t^3+...) $$
One may further note that (quite magically by the way, probably for some underlying reason, from the 7th term it is completely regular?):
$$ Q(t)=q(t)(1+2t+3t^2+4t^3+...) = 1+t+t^2+2t^3+t^4+t^5+t^6+\sum_{k\geq 0} kt^{k+3}$$ So we arrive at
$$ f(t) = (1+t+t^2+2t^3+t^4+t^5+t^6)(1+t^{15}+t^{30}+..) + R(t).$$
The first term is 15-periodic and
$$ R(t) = \sum_{k\geq 1} \sum_{j\geq 0} k \; t^{k+15 j+3} = 
\sum_{n\geq 4} \sum_{j=0}^{j^*}  (n-3-15j)  \; t^{n} =
\sum_{n\geq 4} r_n t^n $$
with $r_n= (j^*+1)(n-3-\frac{15 j^*}{2})$ and $j^*=\lfloor\frac{n-3}{15} \rfloor$.
gives the increasing part.  (But I see that Thomas has got a nice 'explicit' and simple formula)